# how to make the Expected value curve for a longitudinal data in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal data where I would like to make the expected value curve. In the x-axis I have time and in the y-axis I have a continuous variable.

Comment: Have a look to `geom_smooth` in {ggplot2}

Comment: And please, try to give a [mcve] when asking a question in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Without data it is hard to reproduce your problem first I generated some random data:

```
df <- data.frame(Age = sample(1:50),
                 variable = runif(50, 0, 1))
```

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can use `geom_smooth` to create an expected value curve using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Nima, Maybe you can share your own data using `dput(df)`?